# Suppose that $F\subset K\subset L$, field extensions. If [L:K] is infinite, then [K:F] = infinite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

We have $[L:F]=[L:K][K:F]$ if each term is finite.

I claim that if $[L:K]=\infty$ then $[L:F] =\infty$. But I wonder if it can also be concluded that $[K:F]=\infty$.

**Proof of the claim:** Suppose $[L:F]=r$, finite. Since $[L:K]=\infty$, there exist $r+1$ vectors in $L$ which are linearly independent over $K$. These vectors must be linearly dependent over $F$ (because $[L:F]=r$).  But since $F\subset K$, we get a contradiction.

But I don't understand how to prove $[K:F]=\infty$.

**Background**: The book that I am studying this from first remarks that if $[L:K]=\infty$, then $[L:F]=\infty$. I tried to prove that as above. The book uses a slightly different proof. Then, the book says: 'similarly, $[K:F]$ is infinite.' I tried to repeat the same proof I wrote above to prove this but it didn't work. It's a typo as the answer below shows. But the spirit of that probably is the following: If $[L:K]$ or $[K:F]$ is infinite, then $[L:F]$ is infinite.

Comment: Your proof of $[L:F] =\infty$ is off topic. What did you try to prove or disprove your conjecture $[K:F]=\infty$, before asking? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=how+to+ask+a+good+question Look at any proof of $[L:F]=[L:K][K:F]$: it is *always* true (even when some of the 3 terms are infinite).

Comment: @AnneBauval: I tried to repeat the proof that I have written above for proving $[K:F]=\infty$. But it seems that I misinterpreted a statement in the book hence the question. The conjecture is **not** true as the answer below shows.

Comment: Either you misread your book (btw, which is it?) or there is an "if" missing in it. It should be 'similarly, **if** $[K:F]$ is infinite' [then $[L:F]=\infty$], as told in my 1st comment.

Comment: Your conjecture was obviously not true.The 2 points of my comment were: 1) you should have thought a little more before asking 2) the formula is always true and this gave you a bunch of counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Take for example $F=\mathbb Q$, $K=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ and $L=\mathbb R$.